# Nice paraglide spots nearby Geneva (Switzerland) by public transport

Tags: public-transport, france, switzerland, geneva, parachutes-skydiving

The last week of this month (March) I'll be in Geneva. There I would like make a tandemflight. I was wondering what's a nice place (mountainous area) to do this and which will be a cheap way to get there by bus or train.

Has anyone have experience with paragliding nearby Geneva? And is there a way to travel by public transport from Geneva to mountainous spots in Switzerland or France? (where paragliding is possible, eg Morzine or Arâches-la-Frasse)

Comment: Recommendations of particular companies is off topic here. Try tripadvisor. The transport questions are valid though. I'm not sure if March is a good time for this mind - likley to still be snow around, effecting thermals. Not sure if litfs are still open.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question. Well the companies are offering flights in this period so it's possible. Snow is not needed but could be more visual attractive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience in paragliding.

However, I often see people paragliding on the Salève (a small mountain nearby Geneva, accessible by public transport and a cable car).

I also often see people paragliding in Chamonix (Brévent). You can take a bus to Chamonix in the center of Geneva (Gare routière de Genève).

Answer (score 0):

To find flying sites, you can use Gaggle or SkyFlyHy mobile apps, plus a GPS spoofer.

First, search for cable cars or other easy access high mountain locations in the country you're going to visit.  Then set your GPS spoofer to that location and open up your paraglider flight recorder software (presuming it has a social aspect which shows recent flights).  Now you'll see recent flights in the area.  By viewing the track of recent flights, you can see where they've been taking off and landing.

Sometimes you can manage to find a flying club in the destination country.  One way to do this is look on youtube for paraglider videos for the country you're going to visit, and just put a comment on the video.  It's somewhat likely that the pilot will reply with helpful information, like an email address or web page.

Sometimes landing zones are very small.

Here is one in Tromso, Norway, that measures just 50 feet wide by 150 feet long, but it's only a 3 minute walk to the cable car.
[image: Small LZ]